# What is the next number in the sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What could be the next number in the sequence:

> 57, 74, 65, 61, 37, 58, ?

Comment: You should start this sequence with 4 and see what happens... :)

Comment: @Stiv You'd probably end up with something like [this](http://oeis.org/A000216) :)

Comment: Ooh that's nice

Answer (score 9):

The next value is

> 89

The pattern is

> The sum of the squares of each digit of the previous value